# Get rid of duplicate jest.mock

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Using the same ***jest.mock***, returning different results, leads to the accumulation of duplicate code.

I did not find information on how to deal with this and I would like to ask if it is possible to create a function similar to the following:

```
const createMock = (result) => jest.mock('some-module', () => (result));
```

Answer (score 0):

No, It is Immpossible. You should always write a new mock at the top of describe

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jest.mock()` in the module scope of the test file. It will be hoisted to the top of the file before any `import`. Which means the imported module is already mocked. So that you can use `mock.mockReturnValue()` method in each test case to provide a different return value.

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
import someFn from './some-module';

export default function main() {
  return someFn();
}
```

`some-module.js`:

```js
export default function someFn() {
  return 'a';
}
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
import main from './';
import someFn from './some-module';

jest.mock('./some-module');

describe('71219584', () => {
  test('should pass 1', () => {
    someFn.mockReturnValue('fake a');
    console.log(main());
  });
  test('should pass 2', () => {
    someFn.mockReturnValue('fake b');
    console.log(main());
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/71219584/index.test.js
  71219584
    ✓ should pass 1 (17 ms)
    ✓ should pass 2 (2 ms)

  console.log
    fake a

      at Object.<anonymous> (stackoverflow/71219584/index.test.js:18:13)

  console.log
    fake b

      at Object.<anonymous> (stackoverflow/71219584/index.test.js:22:13)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.186 s
```